# UIBarButtonItem doesn't turn gray when presenting popover

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller

It's my understanding that with iOS 7, 8 and 9, when you present a popover in your application, all UIBarButtonItems in a UIToolbar are supposed to automatically be grayed out.

However, most of the time what I get is that only the button you tapped turns gray, and the other buttons remain in their original color.

I built a simple test app with a story board that has:

- a single UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController
- a UIToolbar on that UIViewController
- five UIBarButtonItems in the toolbar (using images)
- segues set to "Present As Popover" from each of the bar button items to another UIViewController

In code, for the UIViewController that presents the popover I have just this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ShowPopover" {
            let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 224.0)

            if let popoverController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController {

                // set the delegate, so adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController is called
                popoverController.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }


    // MARK: - UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate

    // return .None to show as a popover on iPhone too
    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None
    }
}
```

Even with that simple example, when I tap one of the buttons to present the popover, only the tapped button turns gray.

Am I misunderstanding the way UIBarButtonItems are supposed to behave when a popover is presented? Or is this a known iOS SDK bug? Are there any workarounds?

**Update:** I've posted a sample application here that demonstrates the problem, using the iOS 8.4 SDK:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2349787/BarButtonPopover.zip

Comment: Can you upload the sample project somewhere?

Comment: Sure, I've posted a sample project here (using the iOS 8.4 SDK): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2349787/BarButtonPopover.zip

Comment: I'll look into it. Btw: Popovers on iPhone?! In which OS version did they add that?

Comment: Quick question: do you want them all dimmed or all tinted during the presentation?

Comment: Popovers on iPhone started with iOS 8 as part of UIPresentationController.  The buttons should all be gray when the popover appears (at least on a white/light gray toolbar) - as far as I can tell it's a tintColor change.

Comment: I've also tried changing the UIViewTintAdjustmentMode of the toolbar to .Dimmed when the popover is presented, but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The buttons should all be gray when the popover appears (at least on a white/light gray toolbar) - as far as I can tell it's a tintColor change.

It's hard to tell what it *should* be. Take a look at Mail on the iPad. It has the very same behavior your app demonstrates: pressed icon and all other *bars* become dimmed. While I don't agree that this looks good, it apparently is what Apple wants.

> I've also tried changing the UIViewTintAdjustmentMode of the toolbar to .Dimmed when the popover is presented, but that doesn't help either.

I had the very same idea. I swizzled `-setTintAdjustmentMode:` to find out what Apple is doing behind the scenes, and it appears to be some very crazy shit. They **force** the remaining buttons in the bar to be tinted by setting the tint adjustment mode to normal instead of automatic. Hence setting the bar itself to dimmed doesn't show any effect, because the buttons do not inherit the tint adjustment mode.

I would just stick with how it is. Maybe Apple will change the behavior in a future release - and you will always be up to date. If you really want all buttons to be dimmed, you should iterate through all subviews of the bar and set their `tintAdjustmentMode` to automatic. However, I have not figured out when to do this since Apple does not provide an appropriate hook. You will need to do some `-performSelector:afterDelay:0.0` (which just highlights how hacky it is) on some hooks. Programmatic dismissal doesn't even offer any hook at all. Also Apple seems to reconfigure the `tintAdjustmentMode`s upon rotation... There is too much to consider for it to be worth the time in my opinion.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why I assumed all buttons should be dimmed out... and now that I look closer at Apple's apps, the behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes they have it so that even the button the popover is presented from is not dimmed. The general intent seems to be that if a button is tappable even when a popover is shown, then it shouldn't be dimmed - so I'll base design decisions in my own app on that.

Comment: @Jawboxer "The general intent seems to be that if a button is tappable even when a popover is shown, then it shouldn't be dimmed" - that seems like a reasonable idea to me. You said the behavior is inconsistent - can you name an Apple app where this rule would be violated?

Comment: One example of an inconsistency: on iOS 8.2 in the Maps app, none of the buttons are dimmed when a popover is shown even though you can't tap them. However, they appear to have fixed that (in iOS 9 beta 2, possibly earlier).